# Can I make a Dual Throw Double Slice with alchemical bombs and then flense?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

In pathfinder 2, I'm interested in understanding some of the interactions in the feats in the Dual Weapon Warrior archetype.  I'm *particularly* interested in how they function with respect to alchemical bombs... and there it gets *funny*.

- The dual weapon warrior dedication feat comes with Double Slice.  Check.
- the Dual Thrower feat says "Whenever a dual-weapon warrior feat allows you to make a melee Strike, you can instead make a ranged Strike **with a thrown weapon or a one-handed ranged weapon** you are wielding."  This seems to be intended to work with Double Slice (gotten from the dedication) because there is no other strike-providing feat that it could apply to prior to lvl 10.
- Now, nearly every feat in the Dual Weapon Warrior feat tree that Dual Thrower could apply to (ie, those normally generating melee strikes) requires that you be wielding two melee weapons.  Double Slice requires it explicitly.  Dual-Weapon Blitz requires it explicitly.  Twin Riposte requires that you be benefiting from Twin Parry, which requires it explicitly. Twin Defense requires it explicitly. *Technically*, Improved Twin Riposte could trigger without requiring that you wield two melee weapons, but it's a level 16 feat.  Two-weapon Flurry does not, but it also doesn't require Dual Thrower.  If both of your hands are full, you can use both of them.
- It *seems* to me, then, that Dual Thrower is somehow loosening the requirements for those feats.  It looks like the intent of Dual Thrower is to permit things like making two thrown attacks (perhaps using alchemical bombs) with Double Slice, and that if they'd *meant* for it to be limited to only those throwable weapons that are also melee weapons, they wouldn't have included the "or a one-handed ranged weapon" part.  I admit that I'm not clear on that, though.  It's faintly possible that that portion of rules text for a level 4 feat really does only apply to the effects of a level 16 feat that requires a level 12 feat.

Then, assuming that that *does* work, and that Dual Thrower does let me throw two bombs using Double Slice, does Flensing Slice also work?  How does it work?  As far as I can tell, Flensing Slice doesn't actually require another strike.  If you have the feat, and you Double Slice, and you hit with both, you can just immediately spend another action, and the bleed and deuffs happen without need for further dicerolling.  That would suggest that you *could* use it with double-bombing, but the image seems... a bit odd.

So, given all of that confusion, I present the following scenario to clarify exactly what my question is: suppose I'm playing an alchemist.  I've taken the Dual Weapon Warrior dedication feat, the Dual Thrower feat, and the Flensing Slice feat.  I'm standing with an alchemical bomb in each hand, 20 feet away from my target, and the dice gods have blessed me so that all of my attacks will hit.  Can I use all three actions to first Double Slice and then Flensing Slice using the bombs?  If not, then why not?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, per RAW this seems fine

You're logic holds up, and there doesn't seem to be any reason **in the rules** why it wouldn't work. [Alchemical Bombs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=73) are one-handed ranged weapons, so they qualify for [Dual Thrower](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1951) (which, despite the name, isn't for just throwing weapons, which bombs are *not* thrown weapons in the sense of the game term). Dual Thrower states (emphasis mine):

> You know how to throw two weapons as easily as strike with them. Whenever a dual-weapon warrior feat allows you to make a melee Strike, you can instead make a ranged Strike with a thrown weapon or **a one-handed ranged weapon** you are wielding. Any effects from these feats that apply to one-handed melee weapons or melee Strikes also apply to **one-handed ranged weapons and ranged Strikes**.

## The Flavor Issue

You don't seem to state such in your question, but at least from my perspective the primary issue is the flavor. How could someone spend an action to make their bomb's do more damage *after* they've already thrown them? It's... odd, yes. Here is how I would flavor it: after your first attack hits, you, the bomb thrower, know that your second one would also hit (i.e. you've already rolled the hit for the second attack), and so you take extra care to aim in such a way that the shards of the vial shatter and get stuck in the target. I think this captures the flavor of [Flensing Slice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1953).

Comment: The only potential in-the-rules issue I see is that Double Slice explicitly requires that you be wielding two melee weapons, and I'm not seeing how Dual Thrower removes that specific requirement.  Following out that requirement's effects winds up with some vaguely silly implications about what the "or a one-handed ranged weapon" clause was supposed to achieve, but I'm not seeing its removal in the rules.

Comment: @BenBarden but, as you point out, only replacing the Melee Strikes with Ranged Strikes while not altering the requirements would make it still impossible to use Double Slice with any one-handed ranged weapon, so either that clause is totally useless or it means in the requirements as well.